# How to insert pointer in the cassandraDB

Tags: cassandra

I came across a situation where I need to store the class object pointer in cassandra.
Using c++ language for development.

Wanted to store pointer as class contain information regarding buffers (producer consumer buffer of CPP rest SDK) and associated data.

One solution right now i exploring is to store pointer as bigint.

But not sure if this is right approach. I tried to google/stackoveflow but did not find example to store pointers in cassandra.
Any suggestion/pointer on how to store class object pointer would be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `blob` type to store the pointer...

But what is the point of storing pointer to the object that exists on particular machine, and will be destroyed if it's go out of scope, etc.? You can use it only on that machine...

Comment: Thanks  this is what I was looking for...I can't accept or upvote as i have less than 15 reputation point..